# Flutter How to user special text to text widget?

Tags: flutter, text, unicode, widget

hello I wonder how to use U+00B7 this unicode on flutter text widget

I want to use this text. How can I use unicode on flutter Text widget?
thank you so much

Comment: you can use \u00B7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use it simply like this :

```
 Text('\u00a9 example \u00B7'),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the text from api. You can do this:

```
Text(utf8.decode(text.codeUnits)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unicode characters in the text widget simply by doing:

```dart
Text('\u{u00b7} example')
```

This allows unicode characters of greater length(4 and above)